# subrequest in case return error on clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

So i try a make a view , actually this is my code :

```sql
drop table if exists computed_datum_hours_base;
create view computed_datum_hours_base
as select
    toStartOfHour(datetime_value) as datetime_desc,
    computed_id,
    computed_kind,
    computed_type,
    case
        when computed_type = 'intensive' then avg(value)
        when computed_type = 'extensive.some' then sum(value)
        when computed_type = 'extensive.differential' then
            (
                select value as value_f from ref_computed_datum
                where ref_computed_id = computed_id
                and ref_computed_kind = computed_kind
                and ref_computed_type = computed_type
                and ref_datetime_value = toStartOfHour(addHours(datetime_value, 1))
            ) - (
                select value as value_f from ref_computed_datum
                where ref_computed_id = computed_id
                and ref_computed_kind = computed_kind
                and ref_computed_type = computed_type
                and ref_datetime_value = toStartOfHour(datetime_value)
            )
    end as value,
    count(uuid) as nb_value
from computed_datum
    join ref_computed_datum
    on computed_id = ref_computed_id
    and computed_kind = ref_computed_kind
    and computed_type = ref_computed_type
    where uuid = ref_uuid
group by
    computed_id,
    computed_kind,
    computed_type,
    toStartOfHour(datetime_value)
;
```

my issue is on the case for extensive.differential ...
clickhouse say he can found the column for computed_id ... like the subrequest is scoped and didn't have access to the colum from the main requeste ...

So this is another bug of clickhouse ?
Or there are a reel scope and i can't do this like this ...
( so How can do this ? )

Edit: full error

```
Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'datetime_value' 'computed_kind' 'computed_type' 'computed_id' 'value' while processing query: 'SELECT value AS value_f FROM api_client.ref_computed_datum WHERE (ref_computed_id = computed_id) AND (ref_computed_kind = computed_kind) AND (ref_computed_type = computed_type) AND (ref_datetime_value = toStartOfHour(addHours(datetime_value, 1)))', required columns: 'value' 'computed_id' 'ref_computed_id' 'ref_computed_kind' 'computed_type' 'ref_computed_type' 'computed_kind' 'ref_datetime_value' 'datetime_value', source columns: 'ref_flags' 'ref_computed_kind' 'ref_computed_id' 'ref_datetime_value' 'ref_computed_type' 'ref_EventDateTime' 'ref_insert' 'ref_value' 'ref_uuid' (version 20.4.2.9 (official build))
```

computed_datum folow this structure :

````
                EventDateTime  DateTime default now(),
                insert         String,
                uuid           String default generateUUIDv4(),
                datetime_value DateTime,
                computed_id    Int32,
                computed_kind  String,
                computed_type  String,
                value          Float64,
                flags          String
    ```

I make a ref view that only prefix all colum with ref_ for making a walkaround about the alias bug.
````

Comment: just check: if take SQL-query from View and execute it - does it executed without errors?

Comment: *like the subrequest is scoped and didn't have access to the colum from the main request*  Bingo. You probably need to remove the join and rewrite using *Correlated Subqueries* And you might want *conditional aggregation* instead

Comment: @dnoeth i don't understand what you refer with 'conditional aggregation'... for me this is wath i'm doing ...
My rules :
'extensive.differential' => 22h = 23h - 22h / 
'exentive.some' => 22h = 22h10 + 22h20 ...... + 22h50 /
'intensive' => 22h =( 22h10 + 22h20 ...... + 22h50 ) / 6  ( so mean ... )

Can you provide a exemple of correlated subqueries ?

Comment: Correlated subqueries isn't what i'm doing ? ( /!\ clickhouse have a bug with alias :/ ) 
( so i join on a view that juste rename all the column :/ )

Comment: I don't know your rules and expected result, but you use `computed_type` in both `group by` and `case` and thus get individual rows per type.

Comment: Sotty, of course, you're doing *Correlated Subqueries*, but then you probably don't need the join (and this might be the error reason, without aliases you got the column names from ref_computed_datum twice)

Comment: `computed_type` in the group_by isn't realy needed ( a data is a tuple from computed_id and computed_kind ... the type is only for the case ... but i put in the group by for getting the value in the result too ...

Comment: Ho god i think a understand ... so if a want to achieve this without alias a have to create another 2 extra view like ref_computed_datum for only change the column name :/

Comment: could you provide the schema of all tables used in view?

Comment: Not in Standard SQL, removing the join should be enough as the Select in both Correlated Subqueries got their own scope (But I never write those Subqueries without aliases)

Comment: @dnoeth well i try to remove the join , and replace 1 subrequest by a 1 ... same error -_-"

Comment: Try a qualified name `where ref_computed_id = computed_datum.computed_id
                and ref_computed_kind = computed_datum.computed_kind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time clickhouse didn't support correlated query ...

cf: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6697